# I'm trying to create service control policy to block users from creating S3 buckets with public WRITE access, but it's not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create service control policy to block users from creating S3 buckets with public access, but it's not working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": [
                        "public-read-write"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-grant-write": [
                        "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement3",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "s3:x-amz-grant-write-acp": [
                        "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have logged in as root account. This policy is attached to this account, but still I am able to create S3 buckets with public access.

When I log into member account I was able to add public ACL to write.

This is how I am adding the public access under permission access control policy:

[image: public]

Comment: Do you use member account to check? SCP's don't applied to the master account.

Comment: yes I tried with member account as well, it didnt work Im still able to create s3 bucket and add public write acl on it from the console

Comment: When you say "I am able to create S3 buckets with public access", how are you granting that public access? Are you adding a Bucket Policy? Does the console say "Public" next to the S3 bucket? Please edit your question to add this information rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have added my answer to my original question above.Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but could you further clarify the exact steps you took (or provide a screenshot) to explain what you mean by "I was able to add public ACL to write"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I have added the image to the original question thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That "Public Access" section you show in the screenshot does not permit users to *read* the content of an Amazon S3 bucket. The options allow *listing* of the bucket and *writing* objects, but *not* reading objects.

If you wish to block the ability to change the setting shown in your screenshot, then `Deny` use of `s3:PutBucketAcl`. Your policy is doing this, but with the additional condition that the ACL is being set to `public-read-write`, which is not one of the settings for the Bucket ACL. Therefore, you should Deny that action *without* a condition.

However **the true way to protect an Amazon S3 bucket from public access is to use [Block Public Access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/)**. This overrides any other policies that are granting access, such as Bucket Policies or ACLs at the object-level. If Block Public Access is activated, then the bucket will stay private.

From [Service Control Policies - Prevent Users from Modifying S3 Block Public Access Settings](https://asecure.cloud/a/scp_s3_block_public_access/), you can create a Service Control Policy (SCP) to stop an account from changing this setting:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Deny"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to [Using Amazon S3 block public access - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html):

> The DELETE PublicAccessBlock operations require the same permissions as the PUT operations. There are no separate permissions for the DELETE operations.

Therefore, the above policy would also prevent removal of the Block Public Access settings.

If you prevent the account from changing Block Public Access, then **you do not actually need the policy you have shown in your question**. This is because Block Public Access is overriding such settings, so users cannot make buckets or objects public.

Comment: Hi John thank you for your response. the issue we have is that we have requirment for s3 buckets to have public read access so we cannot block s3 bucket being public overall.we only want them to blocked from being public write.

Comment: In that case, Deny `s3:PutBucketAcl` with no condition and see if it fixes things.

Comment: wouldnt that block from us being able to give access to usergroup within the organization .

Comment: Frankly, you should never use Bucket ACLs. You should either use a **Bucket Policy** for granting public access, or grant specific access to IAM Users, Groups, Roles by adding policies directly to those IAM entities.

Comment: our developers use bucketACL quite extensively, it will be massive push to change the behavior.